# How do I write move constructor and assignment operator for a class which has a private object as property?

Tags: c++, class, c++11, assignment-operator, move-constructor

I learned [Move Constructors](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/move_constructor) today. I read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3109981/245376), and I tried to apply the move constructor example in it to my code.

```
class UnicodeString
{
    public:
        enum  ENDIANNESS_TYPE {LITTLE_ENDIAN = 0, BIG_ENDIAN = 1} ENDIANNESS;
        bool  REPLACE_NON_ASCII_CHARACTERS;
        char  REPLACE_NON_ASCII_CHARACTERS_WITH;
        float VECTOR_RESERVE_COEFFICIENT;

        UnicodeString(UnicodeString && Other);

        // ...

        UnicodeString & operator=(UnicodeString Other);

        // ...

    private:
        std::vector<UnicodeChar> UString;

        // ...
}

UnicodeString::UnicodeString(UnicodeString && Other)
{
    this->REPLACE_NON_ASCII_CHARACTERS      = Other.REPLACE_NON_ASCII_CHARACTERS;
    this->REPLACE_NON_ASCII_CHARACTERS_WITH = Other.REPLACE_NON_ASCII_CHARACTERS_WITH;
    this->VECTOR_RESERVE_COEFFICIENT        = Other.VECTOR_RESERVE_COEFFICIENT;
    this->ENDIANNESS                        = Other.ENDIANNESS;
    this->UString = ?????
}

UnicodeString & UnicodeString::operator=(UnicodeString Other)
{
    std::swap(?????, ?????);
    return *this;
}
```

However, unlike in that example, my class `UnicodeString` does not merely contain a simple C array. It contains an `std::vector<>` object whose elements are instances of another class I wrote.

First of all, in the move constructor, how do I *steal* the `UString` vector of the other object passed by R-Value?

Secondly, in the assignment operator, how do I efficiently swap references of `UString`s of the main `UnicodeString` object and the one passed by R-Value? <s>Notice that `UString` is a private property, therefore it cannot be directly accessed from another object</s>.

Comment: `UnicodeString`s should be able to see each others `UString`s not matter if the are `private` or not. The access specifier applies to other customers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> First of all, in the move constructor, how do I steal the UString vector of the other object passed by R-Value?

Just [`move()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/move) the `std::vector` as it is moveable ([`operator=(vector&&)`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/operator%3D)):

```
this->UString = std::move(Other.UString);
```

> Secondly, in the assignment operator, how do I efficiently swap references of UStrings of the main UnicodeString object and the one passed by R-Value? Notice that UString is a private property, therefore it cannot be directly accessed from another object.

Note that `private` applies to the `class`, not to an instance of the `class`. Meaning other instances of the same `class` can access the `private` members of another instance. So, just use `std::move(Other.UString)` as before.

Answer (score 2):

The correct way to do this (assuming that you're using Visual Studio and therefore your compiler won't do it for you) is like this, with an initialization list:

```
Unicode::UnicodeString(UnicodeString && other)
  : this->REPLACE_NON_ASCII_CHARACTERS(other.REPLACE_NON_ASCII_CHARACTERS)
  , this->REPLACE_NON_ASCII_CHARACTERS_WITH(other.REPLACE_NON_ASCII_CHARACTERS_WITH)
  , this->VECTOR_RESERVE_COEFFICIENT(other.VECTOR_RESERVE_COEFFICIENT)
  , this->ENDIANNESS(other.ENDIANNESS)
  , this->UString(std::move(other.UString))
{
}
```

> Notice that UString is a private property, therefore it cannot be directly accessed from another object.

Says who? Private means that code outside of the object can't access it. But one object instance most certainly *can* access the privates of another object instance.